# Can i edit icon in package qrscan flutter?

Tags: flutter

can i change the appearance of the navbar on `scanner.scan();` running ?

I want to edit Flashlight icon and galery icon

`https://ibb.co/LnNKrmg`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Pull request for that package to accept those widgets as optional parameters, or you can fork it and change them yourself and add the forked git dependency to your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I can't find a place to edit the view. can you tell me?